# SSRS 2008 how to show custom Axis

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have been trying to plot the graph of excel below in ssrs
How can I display the time wait so that I can plot the line graph to compare the adult wait and the children wait. This is the table used(data used in excel)

```
DECLARE @CheckIN AS TABLE (CheckINDate DATE, CheckInTime VARCHAR(10),   MinsWaitKid INT,  MinsWaitAdult INT);
INSERT INTO @CheckIN VALUES     
    ('17/10/2016','00:54:21','3261','1620'),
    ('19/10/2016','00:52:32','3152','1617'),
    ('21/10/2016','00:52:08','3128','1564'),
    ('24/10/2016','00:51:45','3105','1591'),
    ('20/10/2016','00:50:56','3056','1548'),
    ('13/10/2016','00:50:47','3047','1565'),
    ('15/10/2016','00:50:31','3031','1615'),
    ('18/10/2016','00:48:17','2897','1455'),
   ('23/10/2016','00:43:30','2610','1636'),
    ('14/10/2016','00:43:14','2594','1560'),
    ('26/10/2016','00:38:17','2297','1602'),
    ('25/10/2016','00:32:48','1968','1327'),
    ('16/10/2016','00:30:09','1809','1598'),
    ('22/10/2016','00:18:57','1137','1635')

    SELECT * FROM @CheckIN
```

See the excel graph bellow[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently had this problem also and didn't have a very good solution, however I did accomplish it this way:
In the **Vertical Axis Properties** (of your graph) > **Number** > **Custom** you can set a **Custom format** for your axis. You can set it to the following expression:

```
="0" + CStr(Int(Fields!MinsWaitAdult.Value/3600)) 
    + ":" + CStr(Int(Fields!MinsWaitAdult.Value/60)) 
    + ":" + RIGHT("0" + CStr(Fields!MinsWaitAdult.Value MOD 60), 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. It works perfectly. more grease to your elbow